# IBOutletCollection objects indexed wrong

Tags: ios, sdk, indexing, iboutletcollection

i have 10 uibuttons on story board and i've linked them with iboutletcollections. Then i set  buttons backgroundimage from array of uiimage using loop. When i run my project button indexes differs from image indexes

---

Here is my code

```
-(void)setButtonImages
{ 
  for (int i=0; i<imageArray.count; i++)
  {
    UIButton *b =[self.myButtons objectAtIndex:i];
    [b setBackgroundImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  }
}
```

Comment: Show some code Соёмбо Бат-Эрдэнэ..

Comment: what does `self.myButtons` have? and `imageArray` have?

Comment: self.myButtons is  iboutletcollection and it has 10 uibuttons from storyboard, imageArray has 10 uiimage objects

Comment: i meant the values... try adding a breakpoint at these lines aor putting 2 NSLogs before the `for` loop

Comment: my problem is button index differs from image index
 it must be looks like this
button[0] = image[0],
button[1] = image[1],
........
button[n] = image[n],

but when i run my code it appears like this:
button[5] = image[1],
button[1] = image[2],
button[9] = image[3] etc

Comment: how could it change the value of `i` .....?

Comment: could you do this `NSLog(@"self.myButtons: %@",self.myButtons);`  `NSLog(@"imageArray: %@",imageArray);` before the loop.

Comment: log result shows normally, there isn't any problem also count of two array are equal that's not problem my budd. Real trouble is indexes are orderless, anyways tnx for your reply and response maybe i have to  use normal mutablearray and define uibutton objects one by one  and add it to my mutable array next time i never use iboutletcollection :D

Comment: Could set `tag`s in IB and sort before using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create your buttons manually then tag them one by one and you can use your buttons with tag